# How Do you display data from an api in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weatherstack

**Weather.JS File**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import WeatherDisplay from './WeatherDisplay'

const Weather = ({capital, params}) => {

const [weather,setWeather] = useState([])

useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('http://api.weatherstack.com/current', {params})
      console.log(result.data)
      setWeather(result.data)
  },

[params])



return(
    <div>
        <h2>Weather in {capital}</h2>
        <WeatherDisplay current={weather.current}/>
    </div>
)
}
export default Weather
```

**WeatherDisplay.js File**

```
const WeatherDisplay = ({weather}) => {
  console.log(weather.current.temperature)
  return (
      <h1>{weather.current.temperature}</h1>
  )
}

export default WeatherDisplay
```

**Having issues display the data when i use {weather.current.temperature}, it keeps giving me an error pointed at temperuture saying it isnt defined but its apart of the data**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing `weather.current` as props. While the child component is expecting `weather` as prop. So, what you end up doing is `weather.current.current.temperature` which is undefined because it doesn't exist. Just pass `weather` to the child prop.

Make this change when calling your child component.

```
<WeatherDisplay weather={weather}/>
```

Comment: Or don't use `weather.current` in the component and just use `weather.tempreture` instead.

Comment: Should also be destructed as `({current})` in the component function or change name of prop in jsx